# Is GRP a subcategory of SET, or not?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, category-theory

This is the notion of a subcategory $\mathscr{D}$ of a given category $\mathscr{C}$ which I use: it consists of a subcollection of the collection of objects of $\mathscr{C}$ and a subcollection of the collection of morphisms of $\mathscr{D}$ such that:

1) if the morphism $f:x\longrightarrow y$ is in $\mathscr{D}$, then so are $x$ and $y$

2) if $f:x\longrightarrow y$ and $g:y\longrightarrow z$ are in $\mathscr{D}$, so is the composite $gf:x\longrightarrow z$

3) if $x$ is in $\mathscr{D}$, then so is the identity morphism $1_X$

Following this definition, the category of groups should be a subcategory of the category of sets. But I have just read on "Universal Algebra" (author Cohn) that: "...it [the category of groups] is not a subcategory [of sets] because distinct groups may have the same carrier."

So how can I decide if it is a subcategory or not?

Comment: Well, is a group a set, or not? Think very carefully.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/495447/5191).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let us write $UG$ for the underlying set of a group $G$.

Well, as ZhenLin pointed, a group as a pair in the set theoretic means $G=(UG,\,\circ)=\{\{UG\},\{UG,\circ\}\}$ has not much to do with the elements of $UG$.

In this sense ${\bf Grp}$ is not strictly a subcategory of ${\bf Set}$.

There exists, however, an *injective* functor ${\bf Grp}\to{\bf Set}$ mapping
$$G\ \mapsto \ UG\times\{G\},$$
and thus its image is a subcategory of ${\bf Set}$ which is isomorphic to ${\bf Grp}$.